# Vim - yank 2nd word of line and append to end of line, multiple times

Tags: vim, vi

I have a file with 3 columns, and I would like to yank the 2nd word and append it to the end of the line. How can I do this? I've tried it with a macro, but it keeps telling me that, e.g.
`E492: Not an editor command: 0whyt $p`

Any thoughts?

Comment: This site doesn't allow me to post "What have you tried?" but I have to say, that is what I am wondering.

Comment: awk may be another way to go. Hard to be sure from your description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you were confused by "macro recording" and "command". You perhaps have done:

```
:0whyt $p<Enter>
```

this is not correct. You should record a macro in normal mode by pressing `q`

### macro

assuming the cursor at line1, col1.

```
qqelye$p+q
```

then `xx@q`

or with recursive macro: `qqelye$p+@qq` then `@q`

```
qq  "start recording in reg q
e   "to the end of 1st col
lye "yank the 2nd col with leading col separator
$p  "append to the EOL
+   "go to next line
```

### :normal

`:normal` is very handy in this case too:

```
:%normal! elye$p
```

well if external awk is counted too:

### awk

```
:%!awk '$0=$0 FS $2'
```

Comment: What awk trickery is this!? I have not seen this trick before. Care to elaborate why you do not need `{...}`?

Comment: @PeterRincker any true (awk evluated as true) will trigger the default action: `print` and if `print` without argument, will be `print $0`. also , any non-empty string, non-zero number will be evaluated by awk as `true` so put them together, `$0=...` is an assignment statement, we set something (non empty) to `$0`, that is `awk 'non-empty' -> awk 'true' -> awk '{print}' -> awk '{print $0}'` the `$0` is the changed `$0`. hope it is cleared now.

Comment: it all makes sense now. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: I used the macro. I think what I did wrong was, in Command Mode, I typed `:74@q` instead of just `74@q`.

Answer (score 0):

This regex substitution will do it:

```
s/\(\S\+\)\(\s\+\S\+\)\(.*\)/\1\3\2/
```

You can perform it on a range by preceding the command with the range bounds.  You can perform it on all lines matching some regex via the `g` command.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a normal command.

```
:%normal 0whyt $p
```

Which will run `0whyt $p` on every line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using AWK:

```
:%!awk {'print $1,$2,$3,$2'}
```

(Peter's is better, though)

And yet another `:normal` solution:

```
:%norm f yE$p
```

And another `:s//` solution:

```
:%s/\v(\S*) (\S*) (\S*)/& \2
```

Comment: vimgolf: `%s/\v( \w+).*/&\1`

Comment: from my vimgolf experience, in most case, normal mode trick (macro E.g.) will beat `:%s/././<cr>`.

Comment: @Kent absolutely! However it is fun to vimgolf with more restrictions like what is the shortest vim golf only using substitution.

Answer (score 0):

### awk

```
awk '{print $0, $2}' foo.txt
```

Or from inside Vim:

```
:%!awk '{print $0, $2}'
```